# Allure report attaches video with size zero in Playwright tests

Tags: allure, cucumberjs, playwright-typescript

```
    import { ICustomWorld } from './custom-world';
import { config } from './config';
import { Allure, ContentType } from 'allure-cucumberjs';
import {
  Before,
  After,
  BeforeAll,
  AfterAll,
  Status,
  setDefaultTimeout,
  AfterStep,
} from '@cucumber/cucumber';
import {
  chromium,
  ChromiumBrowser,
  firefox,
  FirefoxBrowser,
  webkit,
  WebKitBrowser,
  ConsoleMessage,
} from '@playwright/test';
import { ITestCaseHookParameter } from '@cucumber/cucumber/lib/support_code_library_builder/types';
import { ensureDir, ensureFileSync } from 'fs-extra';
import axios from 'axios';
import * as fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';

const screenshots_folder = './screenshots/';
const allure_categories_conf_path = path.join('conf', 'reporters', 'categories.json');
const allure_envProperties_path = path.join('conf', 'reporters', 'environment.properties');
const allure_categories_target_path = path.join('allure-results', 'categories.json');
const allure_envProperties_target_path = path.join('allure-results', 'environment.properties');

let browser: ChromiumBrowser | FirefoxBrowser | WebKitBrowser;
const tracesDir = 'traces';

declare global {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-var
  var browser: ChromiumBrowser | FirefoxBrowser | WebKitBrowser;
}

setDefaultTimeout(process.env.PWDEBUG ? -1 : 60 * 1000);

BeforeAll(async function () {
  switch (config.browser) {
    case 'firefox':
      browser = await firefox.launch(config.browserOptions);
      break;
    case 'webkit':
      browser = await webkit.launch(config.browserOptions);
      break;
    default:
      browser = await chromium.launch(config.browserOptions);
  }
  await ensureDir(tracesDir);
  // Create emptid allure properties files empty in reports folder
  ensureFileSync(allure_envProperties_target_path);
  ensureFileSync(allure_categories_target_path);
});

Before(async function (this: ICustomWorld, { pickle }: ITestCaseHookParameter) {
  const parent_suite = await pickle.uri
    .replace(/[a-zA-Z]+\/[a-zA-Z]+\//i, '')
    .replace('features', '')
    .replace('ui', '')
    .replace('\\\\', '')
    .replace('.feature', '')
    .toUpperCase();
  await this.parentSuite(parent_suite);
});

Before({ tags: '@ignore' }, async function () {
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  return 'skipped' as any;
});

Before({ tags: '@debug' }, async function (this: ICustomWorld) {
  this.debug = true;
});

Before({ tags: '@ui' }, async function (this: ICustomWorld, { pickle }: ITestCaseHookParameter) {
  this.startTime = new Date();
  this.testName = pickle.name.replace(/\W/g, '-');
  // customize the [browser context](https://playwright.dev/docs/next/api/class-browser#browsernewcontextoptions)

  this.context = await browser.newContext({
    acceptDownloads: true,
    recordVideo: { dir: 'screenshots' },
    viewport: null,
  });

  this.server = axios.create();
  this.server.defaults.baseURL = config.BASE_API_URL;
  this.server.defaults.headers.post = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  };
  this.server.interceptors.response.use((res) => res.data);
  // use login and set authorization if needed
  // this.server.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token;

  await this.context.tracing.start({ screenshots: true, snapshots: true });
  this.page = await this.context.newPage();
});

AfterStep(async function (this: ICustomWorld, { result }: ITestCaseHookParameter) {
  if (result?.status != 'PASSED') {
    const image: any = await this.page?.screenshot({ type: 'png' });
    image && (await this.allure?.attachment('screenshot', image, 'image/png'));
  }
});

After(async function (this: ICustomWorld, { result }: ITestCaseHookParameter) {
  if (result) {
    await this.attach(`Status: ${result?.status}, CurrentUrl:${this.page?.url()}`);

    if (result.status !== Status.PASSED) {
      //Add screenshot
      const image = await this.page?.screenshot();
      image && (await this.attach(image, 'image/png'));

      //Add Video
      const video = this.page?.video();
      const videopath = await video?.path();
      await this.page?.waitForTimeout(3000);
      if (video) {
        await this.attach(fs.readFileSync('./' + videopath), 'video/webm');
      }

      await this.context?.tracing.stop({
        path: `${tracesDir}/${this.testName}-${
          this.startTime?.toISOString().split('.')[0]
        }trace.zip`,
      });
    }
  }

  await this.page?.close();
  await this.context?.close();
});

AfterAll(async function () {
  //write environment.properties for allure reporter
  fs.writeFileSync(
    allure_envProperties_path,
    ` Browser = ${config.browser} ${browser.version()} \nEnvironment = prod \nURL = ${
      config.BASE_URL
    }
    `,
  );

  fs.copyFile(allure_categories_conf_path, allure_categories_target_path, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('File was copied to destination');
  });
  fs.copyFile(allure_envProperties_path, allure_envProperties_target_path, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('environment_values are copied to destination');
  });

  // if (fs.existsSync(screenshots_folder)) {
  //   fs.rmSync(screenshots_folder, { recursive: true, force: true });
  // }

  await browser.close();
});
```

I'm encountering an issue with my Playwright tests where the Allure report sometimes attaches videos with size zero, resulting in unusable or empty video attachments in the report. I have configured my tests to record videos using Playwright's built-in functionality, and I'm generating Allure reports to visualize the test results.

The problem seems to occur sporadically, and I haven't been able to pinpoint the exact cause. Has anyone else encountered a similar issue with Allure reports and Playwright tests? If so, how did you resolve it?

I suspect there might be an issue with how I'm handling video recording or attaching videos to the Allure report, but I'm not sure. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!